# Sweet alert 2 solo me sale una vez dentro de un bucle

Tags: php, jquery, sweetalert2

tengo el problema siguiente.
Utilizo sweet alert 2 dentro de un bucle while para que me muestre una alerta por cada registro que cumple unas condiciones (un if dentro del while) pero solo me muestra una alerta, la del último registro. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que por cada registro me muestre una alerta?.

```
while(xxxxx){
if(!empty($temp[0]['fk_incidencia']) AND $ultimo_est['nombre'] == "Resuelta" OR $ultimo_est['nombre'] == "Resuelta SAT" AND $temp[0]['aviso'] == '1'){
                var_dump($temp[0]['fecha_inicio']."</br>");
                ?>
                <script>
                    Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Incidencia con cita',
                    text: "Se a encontrado un registro con cita, nº de incidencia: <? echo $temp[0]['fk_incidencia']; ?>",
                    icon: 'info',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#2b77c0',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: '<a style="color: white; background-color: #2b77c0; text-decoration-line: none;" href="_mis_incidencias.php?opciones_cita=editar_cita&fecha_inicio=<? echo $temp[0]['fecha_inicio']; ?>&fecha_fin=<? echo $temp[0]['fecha_fin']; ?>&id_incidencia=<? echo $Incidencia->get_Id(); ?>&fk_incidencia=<? echo $temp[0]['fk_incidencia']; ?>&descripcion_cita=<? echo $temp[0]['descripcion']; ?>&aviso=<? echo $temp[0]['aviso']; ?>">Editar cita</a>',
                    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
                    })
                </script>
                <?
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto, donde lo que hacemos es usar [async()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) y [await()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) para ir mostrando las peticiones asíncronas, y lo ponemos todo en una función que ejecutamos al final:

```php
$swals = '';
while(xxxxx){
    if(!empty($temp[0]['fk_incidencia']) AND $ultimo_est['nombre'] == "Resuelta" OR $ultimo_est['nombre'] == "Resuelta SAT" AND $temp[0]['aviso'] == '1'){
        var_dump($temp[0]['fecha_inicio']."</br>");
        $swals .= '
            await Swal.fire({
            title: "Incidencia con cita",
            text: "Se ha encontrado un registro con cita, nº de incidencia: '.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'",
            icon: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#2b77c0",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: \'<a style="color: white; background-color: #2b77c0; text-decoration-line: none;" href="_mis_incidencias.php?opciones_cita=editar_cita&fecha_inicio='.$temp[0]['fecha_inicio'].'&fecha_fin='.$temp[0]['fecha_fin'].'&id_incidencia='.$Incidencia->get_Id().'&fk_incidencia='.$temp[0]['fk_incidencia'].'&descripcion_cita='.$temp[0]['descripcion'].'&aviso='.$temp[0]['aviso'].'">Editar cita</a>\',
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar"
            })
        ';
    }
}

$salida_script = '
<script>
async function incidencias() {
    '.$swals.'
}
incidencias();
</script>';

echo $salida_script;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me a funcionado a la perfección amigo. Ahora buscaré como funciona async() y await() para entender bien lo que hace. Un saludo